# Is it possible to make a postback to a form by javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

i have a form like this in domain1.com

```
    <form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

In domain2.com , i have a button

```
<button onclick="function()">Click Me</button>
```

, i want if user is opening domain1.com , and then they open domain2.com and click on the button, a postback will be made and unblock the submit button in form of domain1.com , is it possible?
I know that it need javascript but i am just a newbie and have some exp with PHP, please help me.
Thank you and sorry for my bad English :P

Comment: read about localStorage or cookie something like that. that will help you

Comment: Do you have different domain or different webpage??

Comment: i have different doamin